# Cross product with basis vectors different from i, j, and k

Tags: linear-algebra

A student just asked me about the possibility of a cross product defined in terms of a nonstandard basis, that is, don't use i, j, and k.

Can anyone point me to an article explaining such a question, if it exists?

Comment: The cross product can be defined [geometrically](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129) (scroll down to *Geometric Definition* under *The Cross Product*).  Or you do it the algebraic way and just convert to $\{i, j, k\}$, take the cross, then convert back.

Comment: Or, come to think of it, use approach #3: the matrix approach.  You want to compute the cross product $a\times b$, then in $\{i,j,k\}$ that's the same as the matrix multiplication $[a]_\times b$, where [$[a]_\times$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication).  If you'd like to express that linear transformation in a different basis, just do a change of basis transformation on the matrix $[a]_\times$.

Comment: For   $v=v_1\times v_2$, we have $v$ orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$, and the distance from $v$ to the origin $ O$ is twice the area of the triangle $O v_1 v_2$. This gives 2 possible values for $v$. The usual choice is that $(1,0,0)\times (0,1,0)=(0,0,1)$ and that  "$\times$" is continuous in each variable. This uniquely determines all $u\times v$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. See [this great discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/is-cross-product-defined-on-vector-space) and the paper suggested by @Bye_World. Also, if you are just dealing with $\mathbb{R}^n$, then any vector $a,b$ has a representation under a 'non-standard basis', and so you could compute $a,b$ under that non-standard basis and then use those basis vectors instead.